# How do you get up the endless stairs on Super Mario 64 for Nintendo 64?

Tags: super-mario-64

Do you need a certain amount of Stars or is there another way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you have **70 stars**, the staircase is no longer endless and you reach the door at the top.

Or the long jump trick **to reach the top of the staircase without 70 stars** is:

> Do a long jump away from the stairs, then tilt the control stick up. Mario should still be doing long jumps and facing you, but at the same time going up the stairs instead of down. Press the jump button as fast as you can, and Mario will eventually make it up the stairs.
>
> P.S.-- in the DS version the only way to do it, if even possible is to use a mod like action replay to have all the stars {in which case you will already have 70}
>   so there is absolutely no way to do it becasue DS makes it impossible

([source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080707081426AAHHw2v))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it gets unlocked after a certain number of stars, but you can also cheat, and long jump up it. It's difficult though.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the long jump thing. I'm pretty sure the staircase is not climbable...

Comment: @Ricket it is, but you have to do it a specific way, there are a few speedruns of Mario that longjump up it to complete the game.

Answer (score 0):

Stars and long jumps work and there is 1 more way that might not work... Try to run faster when reaching the end. This makes a short glitch, but you STILL have to pay stars. ^v^

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you still have to pay stars, why go through the trouble? Is it a smaller amount of stars? When does the glitch you speak of occur?